# subscribe 2 nodes

Tags: ros, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how to subscribe 2 nodes?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286074/subscribe-2-nodes/) by [zqx](https://answers.ros.org/users/34048/zqx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2018-03-21

Post score: -2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should go through the [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials).

Specifically the tutorial on subscribing to nodes in [C++](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) and [Python](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29).

---

Originally posted by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) with karma: 929 on 2018-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2